# Unwanted break with tcolorbox inside a figure

Tags: floats, tcolorbox, bugs

**Problem:**
I'm trying to use a `tcolorbox` inside a figure but it looks like my custom `maketitle` command lets the box break itself. How can I prevent that?

Note that I really need the `\tcbset{breakable}` because in my full document, a lot of boxes needs the option and I don't want to manually manage this problem by creating another box type without the `breakable` option.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper, margin=1.75cm, bottom=1.25cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{breakable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Variables
\newcommand{\letitre}{Cours Général}
\newcommand{\lesoustitre}{L'Enfance}
\newcommand{\matiere}{Philosophie}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
\vspace*{1cm}
\begin{flushright}
{\bfseries \huge\letitre\\[3pt]}
{\Large\itshape \lesoustitre}\\[3pt]
{\large NVV -- MP1 -- $\displaystyle\int_2^3 x\,\mathrm{d}x$}
\vspace{1cm}
\end{flushright}
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{figure}
\begin{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[1]\lipsum[2]\lipsum[3]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Second page preview:**

[image]

Comment: Use `breakable=false` in the options of the box that should absolutely not be `breakable`.

Answer (score 2):

You can force a single box to not be `breakable` locally by setting `breakable=false` in its options. You could also automatically set this option in `figure` environments (as `breakable` doesn't make any sense there anyways).

The following uses `\AddToHook` to do the latter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper, margin=1.75cm, bottom=1.25cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{breakable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Variables
\newcommand{\letitre}{Cours Général}
\newcommand{\lesoustitre}{L'Enfance}
\newcommand{\matiere}{Philosophie}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
\vspace*{1cm}
\begin{flushright}
{\bfseries \huge\letitre\\[3pt]}
{\Large\itshape \lesoustitre}\\[3pt]
{\large NVV -- MP1 -- $\displaystyle\int_2^3 x\,\mathrm{d}x$}
\vspace{1cm}
\end{flushright}
}

\AddToHook{env/figure/begin}{\tcbset{breakable=false}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{figure}
  \begin{tcolorbox}
    \lipsum[1]\lipsum[2]\lipsum[3]
  \end{tcolorbox}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]